# Bootstrap button not working in media devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have created `bootstrap` button ,it's working fine in `desktop` but button not shown in `media` devices (mobile,tablets).Here is my button [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7hXj.png)

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>              
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-xs-12"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="width:200px;font-size:30px; transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin: right, top;
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform-origin:left, top;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin:left,center;
position: fixed; bottom: 30%; left: 90%;
color:white;" class="btn btn-success">Order</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be your the style of the button, more exactly the `left: 90%;`. Replace `left: 90%; with right: -73px;`. It's working for me.

Comment: Thanks for response.But using right button move to right.I want button on the left side and attached with left side .Thanks

Comment: kindly check this screenshot :( please help.I want in `media` devices `order` button display blow,not from top.[link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29fwe1x&s=9)

Answer (score 0):

problem is with 
position: fixed; bottom: 30%; left: 90%;
replace it with something like this.
position: fixed; bottom: 30%; right: -5%;

Comment: kindly check this screenshot [LINK](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29fwe1x&s=9#.WDgUB7IrLIU)  :( please help.I want in media devices order button display blow,not from top.

Comment: to achieve this i recommend you to use media quires. adjust percentages for different screen sizes.

Comment: I'm already using media queries in my website and i have place this button.I'm new in bootstrap so i am confused :(

Comment: but media quires, the best tool for responsiveness.

Comment: how can i use this?can you give me idea?